# gcc throwing -Wint-to-pointer-cast despite the variable types are the same(from multiboot_uint64_t to multiboot_uint64_t*)

Tags: c, gcc-warning

Here's the code that triggers the warning(`public_mbd` is a `struct multiboot_info`):

```
multiboot_uint64_t* fadr;
fadr=(multiboot_uint64_t*)public_mbd->framebuffer_addr;
```

the definition of `framebuffer_addr` and the struct is as follow:

```
struct multiboot_info{
...
multiboot_uint64_t framebuffer_addr;
...
}
```

gcc said:

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

I'm getting really confused by that. Isn't `fadr` a `multiboot_uint64_t*`? They are the same size!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression

```
public_mbd->framebuffer_addr
```

is of type

```
multiboot_uint64_t
```

You attempt to cast it to type `(multiboot_uint64_t*)`, i.e. a *pointer* to a `multiboot_uint64_t`. It appears that on your architecture the types `multiboot_uint64_t` and pointers have different sizes, but that is not really important; direct casting from a type to a pointer to that type is almost never the right thing to do.

Perhaps you wanted the variable `fadr` to *point to* `public_mbd->framebuffer_addr`. This you can achieve by

```
fadr = &(public_mbd->framebuffer_addr);
```

Alternatively, of course, you may avoid pointers altogether and write

```
multiboot_uint64_t fadr;
fadr = public_mbd->framebuffer_addr;
```

Another possibility is that the structure is incorrectly specified. If you want the `framebuffer_addr` field itself to be a pointer, you would write

```
struct multiboot_info{
  ...
  multiboot_uint64_t* framebuffer_addr;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I want the value of fadr is the value of public_mbd->framebuffer_addr, not the address of public_mbd->framebuffer_addr.

Comment: Then don't use pointers at all. If you declare `fadr` as `multiboot_uint64_t fadr`, without any pointer, then you can assign the value of `public_mbd->framebuffer_addr` directly to `fadr`.

Comment: @ClementPoon So your design is faulty. Why do you use a `multiboot_uint64_t` if you want a pointer to `multiboot_uint64_t`?

Comment: Possibly it is the structure that is poorly designed, I will add to the answer...

Answer (score 2):

It's not `faddr` that is the problem. It is the cast that is the problem.

From the type it is clear that `multiboot_uint64_t framebuffer_addr` is 64 bit. And from the warning we can guess that pointers are 32 bit for your build. So the warning is telling you that you are casting a 64 bit `int` to a 32 bit pointer.